# How to set SOAP request to use SoapClient in php?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am trying to use php SoapClient to consume this SOAP api but which seems to be not working.  Can any of you please guide me?

This is the request sample:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://www.example.com/interface/">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <par:Header>
             <par:UserName>USERNAME</par:UserName>
             <par:Password>PASSWORD</par:Password>
          </par:Header>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <par:GetExampResult>
             <par:rollNumber>1703011</par:rollNumber>
          </par:GetExampResult>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

This is how i tried to convert it to Soap client and not working.

```
    $username = 'USERNAME';
    $password = 'PASS';

    $soapURL = "http://www.example.com/interface.asmx?WSDL";

    $client = new \SoapClient($soapURL);

    $auth = [
      'SamplingSoapHeader' => [
        'UserName' => $username,
        'Password' => $password,
      ],
    ];
    $header = new \SoapHeader('http://www.example.com/interface/',
      'RequestorCredentials', $auth);
    $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);
    $response = $client->GetExampResult(["rollNumber" => "1703011"]);
    print_r($response);
```

Thanks

Comment: First you'll need to give a more useful description than "not working". https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You wrapped your Soapheader into an additional XML Tag:

```
<RequestorCredentials>
    <SamplingSoapHeader>
        <Username>XYZ</Username>
        <Password>123</Password>
    </SamplingSoapHeader>
<RequestorCredentials>
```

In the Soapheader ctor Set the Name to SamplingSoapHeader instead of RequestorCredentials and let $auth be an Array containing only Username and Password instead of wrapping it into SamplingSoapHeader.